# Error : svn path not found

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, spring-tool-suite

While trying to add repository in STS(Spring tool suite) for cheking out project, I am getting error as "svn path not found". But with same url i am able to checkout project in the folder(not through STS).

Comment: error coming as: Location information has been specified incorrectly SVN:E160013 : '/xxx/xxx' path not found : 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

Check your svn plugin is compatible with your STS tool version.

If you installed compatible svn plugin in your STS tool,
Please check whether your svn interface is correctly choose or not.

(Click Preferences -> Team -> SVN - SVN Interface: Choose JAVA HL (JNI 1.8.9) or SVN Kit)

Comment: There is no SVN Interface under SVN.

Comment: Yes I have tried with both JAVA HL and SVN Kit all version

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the already installed svn repository plugin. I installed new Subclipse from Eclipse market place and its working now.